# Parse XML into an array in order

Tags: arrays, node.js, xml, xml-parsing, node-expat

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<Item prop="foo">
  <A key="1">
  <B key="2">
  <A key="3">
  <C key="4">
  <A key="5">
  <A key="6">
</Item>
<Item .../>
<Item .../>
```

I want to parse this file into an array of `Item`s, looking like the following:

```
[
  {
    "prop": "foo",
    "list": [
      { "key": "1" },
      { "key": "2" },
      { "key": "3" },
      { "key": "4" },
      { "key": "5" },
      { "key": "6" }
    ]
  },
  { ...item }
  { ...item }
]
```

I.e. to process all the `A`, `B` and `C` tags *in order* and into the *same array*.

I am using `xml2json`, which uses `node-expat` to parse the file. Is this at all possible using `node-expat` or any existing `npm` package? The reason I ask is because I don't want to be writing my own parser in a compiled language if at all possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the number of node `A`, `B`, `C` small and known?

If so, you can try [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro) like below

EDIT: xml has to be valid, in the example above, it's not properly closed.

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const xml = `
<Item prop="foo">
  <A key="1"/>
  <B key="2"/>
  <A key="3"/>
  <C key="4"/>
  <A key="5"/>
  <A key="6"/>
</Item>
`

const { output } = transform(xml, {
    output: [
        '//Item',
        {
            prop: '@prop',
            list: ['A|B|C', { key: '@key' , tag: 'name()'}]
        }
    ]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "list": [
      {
        "key": "1",
        "tag": "A"
      },
      {
        "key": "2",
        "tag": "B"
      },
      {
        "key": "3",
        "tag": "A"
      },
      {
        "key": "4",
        "tag": "C"
      },
      {
        "key": "5",
        "tag": "A"
      },
      {
        "key": "6",
        "tag": "A"
      }
    ],
    "prop": "foo"
  }
]
```

Comment: This look great, but I'm getting the following warning: `(node:3186) Warning: N-API is an experimental feature and could change at any time.`. Is this production ready?

Comment: Another question: would it be possible to add, as a property of the object, the tag which was matched by `A|B|C`? I.e. to have something like `{"key":"4","tag":"C"}` for each item.

Comment: @felamaslen please use version 2.x.x. Ver 3 is using latest N-API which is still experimental feature.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. it should be updated to be like this `list: ['A|B|C', { key: '@key' , tag: 'name()'}]`